# Does the js HTTP request hadling change in call back functions and immediate execution?

Tags: javascript, http, callback, fetch-api

When i call immediately function contains http requests it return the results. But when i bundle it as a call back function for a even listener it shows errors as ,
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
error is  NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

```
const signupButton = document.getElementById("signup-button");
signupButton.addEventListener("click", postStudent);
// postStudent();

function postStudent() {
if (signupButton === null) {
 console.log("Null");
}
let email = document.getElementById("floatingInput").value;
let password = document.getElementById("floatingPassword").value;

console.log("HI");

let student = {
 email: email,
 password: password,
};

fetch("http://localhost:8080/LogIn", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(student),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  }).then((res) => {
     return res.json();
  })
   .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
  })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
  });
  }
```

Comment: Just a stab into dark, the button is a submitter element and it submits a form, reloading the page, which aborts the AJAX request.